# iPhone sdk how to store crash report

Tags: iphone, crash, report

can anybody tell me how to store crash report from iPhone Native application or Error Reports

Answer (score 4):

you can get your device crash report from here -

On the Mac, crash logs are kept at:
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

On Windows Vista -

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

On Windows Xp -

C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter/

Comment: I thought he is asking about iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you're an iOS developer you can open the Organizer window in either Xcode 3 or 4 and select the "Device Logs" tab to review reports, including crashes.